writing empirical covariance operator as the multiplication of sampling operator (elaboration on a paper)
I have been reading this paper (page 85) and have difficulty to understand that how the empirical version of the covariance operator is $\hat{C}_{XX} = \frac{1}{n} S_x^\ast S_x$ can be written as multiplication of sampling operator?
We have an i.i.d. sample $(x_1, y_1), \ldots, (x_n, y_n)$ from $P(X,Y)$. Define sampling operators $S_x$ and $S_y$ as $S_xf = (f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n))^T$ and $S_yg = (g(y_1), \ldots, g(y_n))^T$ respectively.
The adjoint of these operators are given by $S^\ast$: $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$, $\alpha \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_i k(x_i, \cdot)$, and $S^\ast \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{G}$, $\beta \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_i l(y_i, \cdot)^T$. where $\alpha = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)^T$ and $\beta = (\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n)^T$.
Then, the empirical estimator of the covariance operator is given by
$$\hat{C}_{XX} = \frac{1}{n} S_x^\ast S_x$$
$$\hat{C}_{YX} = \frac{1}{n} S_y^\ast S_x$$
